# How to set place holder in swt text box without using SWT.SEARCH style

Tags: swt, rcp

I have a SWT textbox to which I would like to add a place holder text. Now this textbox is not intended to behave as a search textbox, its a normal textbox and hence I do not want to add the style of SWT.SEARCH. But just by calling setMessage(), the place holder text is not visible.

How to show the place holder without using the style SWT.SEARCH ?

Comment: setMessage works OK without SWT.SEARCH on macOS, but I think this may vary depending on the OS.

Comment: Tried in windows 10, it does not work alone. It needs SWT.SEARCH

Comment: My bad, I was creating the textbox as multi line and expecting it to show placehoder.  SWT.SEARCH was actually enforcing the text to be made as SINGLE and hence was able to see placeholder. We can close this discussion.